# CakePHP 1.2 export into PDF format

Tags: mysql, pdf, cakephp-1.2

Please help. I need a CakePHP 1.2 code that needs to export data from my database to an PDF printable page. This needs to happen when a visitor to my site clicks on the print page button.

Help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use TCPDF library. Here's a link to Cake Bakery explaining how to integrate it in cake.

[Creating Pdf files with Cakephp and TCPDF](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/kalileo/2010/06/08/creating-pdf-files-with-cakephp-and-tcpdf)

Comment: Ok thanx, that is helpful, but I already tried that. I get stuck with the view and my button. I can't seem to figure out how to get my button working with my view! If this makes any sense?

Comment: Just redirect user on pdf view on button click.